# DB2 Express-C on Mac OS X

Tags: db2, installation, mac-os-x

I have followed all the steps described on the [Getting Started with DB2 Express v9.7](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/data/sw-library/db2/express-c/wiki/Getting_Started_with_DB2_Express_v9.7.pdf) e-book and installed DB2 Express-C on my Mac. The installation succeeded without a problem.

I did setup OS X according to this blog post: http://programmingzen.com/2009/01/20/installing-db2-on-mac-os-x/

After the installation, I set up the DB2 instance environment as instructed and was able to start DB2 with:
`$ db2start`

But I was unable to run db2fs. It returns the following error message:

```
$ db2fs
sh: /Users/ivan/sqllib/java/jdk64/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory DB2JAVIT : RC = 127
```

What else do I have to setup in order to make it work on my system?

Comment: I had this same problem. The way I resolved it was to create a symbolic link to OS X's java installation. `cd ~/sqllib/java/jdk64; sudo ln -s /Library/Java/Home jre`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like DB2 doesn't know where Java is installed.

See the following three links for related information.

[Link One](http://listserv.sap.com/pipermail/linux.general/2006-March/004876.html)

[Link Two](http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/623463-db2fs-failed-start)

[Link Three](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/installing-java-46025/)

I realize these are for Linux and you are on Max OSX, but Mac's OS is a variant of Unix, so the solution should be similar.

Comment: Two of those I had already tried prior to asking here. OS X's Java installation doesn't follow the structure of Linux's. For instance, on my system Java is installed on `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`. It doesn't have a `jre/` directory, and if I set db2's `JDK_PATH` to that, it'll assume there's a `jre/` and won't find `java`.

Comment: @ivanmp - so where is your JRE installed?

Comment: On the path I outlined above: `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`.

Comment: Anyway, I was able to make it work thanks to your answer. I re-read one of the links you gave me which I had already tried and although not exactly what I needed, it made me think of a solution, so I'm marking your answer as correct, ok? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ivanmp it would be nice if you'd post your working solution as an answer...

Answer (score 4):

To make it easier for future users to find a working answer:

It appears that one method to fix this problem is to create a symlink from the DB2 location to the Java Home you wish to use. Since I told DB2 to use my user when I installed it (this is for a development copy), the command I used to fix this problem was:

`sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_29-b11-402.jdk/Contents/Home/ ~/sqllib/java/jdk64/jre`