# Cannot install DB2 Express C 10.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: db2, installation

When I invoke ./db2setup it cannot find the JRE where it expects it.  Binary for Java not found as follows:

/private/tmp/db2/expc/db2/macos/install/db2setup: line 606: /tmp/db2.tmp.740/db2/macos/install/../java/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory

I successfully installed DB2 Express C 9.7 last summer before when I was still using the Apple JDK.  I am now getting the JDK from Oracle as it is the only source I know of.

How do I tell the DB2 install where to find Java?

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15791/db2-express-c-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Please check this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=467665&tstart=0 Thanks
Vineet