# Cannot install DB2 Express-C 10.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: db2

I'm having troubles seting up DB2 Express-C 10.1 on my Mac OS X (v10.7.5). My initial install attempt failed, but then I found

```
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797
```

That seemed to work up to the point where I tried to start the db:

```
$ ./db2start 
dyld: Library not loaded: /db2unix/db2galileo/db2_galileo_darwinport/darwin64/s120905/engn/lib/libdb2e.dylib  
Referenced from: /Users/home/sqllib/adm/./db2start  
    Reason: image not foundTrace/BPT trap: 5
$
```

OTOH, if I try to run db2setup from the expc directory I get and error message that others have seen. Something like

```
/Applications/expc/db2/macos/install/db2setup: line 606:     
/tmp/db2.tmp.22412/db2/macos/install/../java/jre/bin/java: No such file or  directory
```

Where the 5-digit number in the tmp directory name changes on each run.

That is followed by a nice DB2 10.1 intro screen which is suddenly replaced by a blank DB2JDKTester window that says "DB2 SETUP LAUNCHPAD" at the top.

Has anyone else tried to install DB2 on Mac OS X 10.7?

(And, yes, I've seen the other thread with the same title, but that was never actually answered.)

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15791/db2-express-c-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Yes, I saw it. The that didn't work for me, but I got it working now as I'm about to explain below.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by completely uninstalling db2 express-c (the db2_deinstall script failed so I manually deleted all directories that involved db2. :P ) .

Then I followed
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797

and it worked. I never ran db2_setup.